# Filtering is not working properly for Name and Description selection?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, checkbox, ng-filter

I am trying to do one task of angularjs grid from google searching which is having sorting, pagination and filtering. Sorting and Pagination are working fine, but filtering is not working properly.

I would like to filter the data based on my `Name` and `Description` checkbox selection. If we observe clearly, for example: if I select any name(either `name1 or name2 or name3` checkbox) of `Name` column, then it's relevant data should display. But what I am getting is: it is displaying all the data which belongs to `Name` column based on my checkbox selection criteria(that's fine), but also displaying the data wherever `name1` is aapplicable/available(from `Description` column too), and similarly it is working the same for `Description` checkbox selection criteria too.

But it should not display like that, it should display only the data based on my either `Name or Description checkbox` selection criteria from the `respective Name/Description column` only, but not from both the columns that wherever it is aapplicable/available), **that is:** if I select any filter name(either `name1 or name2 or name3` checkbox) of `Select Name` dropdown, then it's relevant data should display, means I should see only "name1" in Name column(but it is giving with name3 also), similarly for `Description` checkboxes.

Created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/SAWsA/7079/). Please help me that what and where I am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Placing your code on some third-party site is useless to future visitors when that link breaks down. Put your minimal, relevant code that shows the problem here or this question will soon be deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question quite right, but you could use your own filter function.

I've slightly modified your fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/18se6jqu/1/). Basically I've added a new `$scope.filterItems` function and modified the markup accordingly. It's just an example, you need to modify it for your needs.

Is this what you were after?

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually what I need is: filtering is working, but with some bugs like: if I select any filter name(either name1 or name2 or name3 checkbox) of Select Name dropdown, then it's relevant data should display, means I should see only "name1" in Name column(but it is giving with name3 also), similarly for Description checkboxes.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you can achieve with your own filter function as I shown in my example fiddle, I suggest you re-check it.

Comment: I have re-checked your fiddle, it is not working as per my requirement, Could you please re-check my fiddle once, you can come to know that what I am getting wrong ?(by selecting respective checkboxes and then you can observe the data and it's pagination too). Thanks in advance,

Comment: As I've stated in my answer, it's just an example to how to write your own custom filter function. I've updated my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/18se6jqu/2/), but I would say it's not really a sophisticated code like this.

Comment: Actually, one more update (http://jsfiddle.net/18se6jqu/3/), because checking-unchecking a description checkbox its value would be an empty string and that shouldn't be a valid find.

Comment: yes, I have understood the fiddle now, Thank you for your help and support ! It is grateful to know something today !! Once again thank you for your solution !!

Comment: I have one query that how can I filter with multiple selections(like with name1 and description1, so that I can see name 1 in Name column and description 1 in Description column) ?